# How to add header and footer inside of div?

Tags: html, css

How to add header and footer for the Topic and End for p tag inside of div tag using pure html and css.

I have done it but I am unable to set its footer as I am going nuts with the alignment.

How to add some tweaks to CSS for header and footer part:

I have created a div container inside of which i have created another div that hold content inside of container div .

Can anyone suggest me with this:

```css
.masonry {
  /* Masonry container */
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  margin: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease all;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    <p>TOPIC</p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit.
    <p>END</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>TOPIC</p>
    Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get
    their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no
    idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears.
    <p>END</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I need: for each item div

[image]

Comment: You have to explain better what you want the end result to look like. Otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: Hi @anatolhiman hi i have updated my question

Comment: Hey @PURU css grid is your best friend. See here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Hi @Benny can you tell me how i can use over here

Comment: @PURU I see you have received good help. However, I suggest you use accessible, up to date HTML and wrap your header in a `<header>` element and the footer in a `<footer>` instead of just div's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right, you can wrap the content you want inside a `div` :

```css
.masonry {
  /* Masonry container */
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  margin: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease all;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
}
.item-header{
  padding: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.item-body{
  padding: 1em;
}
.item-footer{
  padding: 1em;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    <!-- header-->
    <div class="item-header">
       <p>TOPIC</p>
    </div>
    <!-- body -->
    <div class="item-body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <!-- footer-->
    <div class="item-footer">
       <p>END</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-header">
       <p>TOPIC</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum
      dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="item-footer">
       <p>END</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Hans Felix Ramos thanx for help can I  fill first row then move to next row . Currently i am filling first  column then moving to next column

Answer (score 0):

You can defined class header and footer, and add class to p tag as

```
.header{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #848d95;
}

.footer{
 border-top: 1px solid #848d95;
}
```

If you want to border item, can set `border radius` as

```
.item{
 border: 1px solid  #848d95;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```css
.masonry {
  /* Masonry container */
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  margin: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease all;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
  border: 1px solid  #848d95;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.header{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #848d95;
}

.footer{
 border-top: 1px solid #848d95;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    <p class="header">TOPIC</p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit.
    <p class='footer'>END</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="header">TOPIC</p>
    Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get
    their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no
    idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears.
    <p class='footer'>END</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to modify your code in order to end up with less lines and keep it fully responsive.

I used two flexboxes: one for `.masonry` which is oriented horizontally (row) and one for `.item` which is oriented vertically (column). The paragraphs inside the items are centered horizontally.

```css
.masonry {
  /* Masonry container */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease all;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
}

.item p {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .masonry .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .masonry .item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .masonry .item {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
  .masonry .item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    <p>TOPIC</p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    <p>END</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>TOPIC</p>
    Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears.
    <p>END</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>TOPIC</p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    <p>END</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>TOPIC</p>
    Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears.
    <p>END</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide your div structure to header, body and footer. Please check below example

```css
        .masonry {
            /* Masonry container */
            -webkit-column-count: 4;
            -moz-column-count: 4;
            column-count: 4;
            -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
            -moz-column-gap: 1em;
            column-gap: 1em;
            margin: 1.5em;
            padding: 0;
            -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
            -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
            column-gap: 1.5em;
            font-size: 0.85em;
        }

        .item {
            display: inline-block;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 1em;
            margin: 0 0 1.5em;
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-transition: 1s ease all;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
        }

        h3.header {
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 0.5em 0;
        }

        .item-body {
            padding: 1em 1em;
        }

        h3.footer {
            text-align: center;
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 1em 0px;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
            .masonry {
                -moz-column-count: 1;
                -webkit-column-count: 1;
                column-count: 1;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {
            .masonry {
                -moz-column-count: 2;
                -webkit-column-count: 2;
                column-count: 2;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
            .masonry {
                -moz-column-count: 3;
                -webkit-column-count: 3;
                column-count: 3;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
            .masonry {
                -moz-column-count: 4;
                -webkit-column-count: 4;
                column-count: 4;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
        <div class="item">
            <h3 class="header">TOPIC</h3>
            <div class="item-body"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
            <h3 class="footer">END</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h3 class="header">TOPIC</h3>
            <div class="item-body"> Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get
                their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no
                idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears.</div>
            <h3 class="footer">END</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```